# Shadows not rendering right in .NET MAUI

Tags: android, maui

The shadows are not rendering the same between devices. On my simulated Pixel 5 on Android 13 the shadows are rendered right with the right radius, while on my physical Xiaomi 11T(Android 13) I get no effect from changing the shadow radius at all. An old Samsung J6 renders the shadows just fine as well. Below are images showing this as well as the code I am using.

Pixel 5:
[image]

Xiaomi 11T:
[image]

And this is the code:

```
<Grid HeightRequest="150" BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
    <RoundRectangle Margin="10" CornerRadius="15" Fill="white" Stroke="silver">
        <RoundRectangle.Shadow>
            <Shadow Brush="black" Offset="5,10" Radius="10" Opacity="0.5"/>
        </RoundRectangle.Shadow>
    </RoundRectangle>
</Grid>
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT:

I posted this as an issue on the MAUI repo and it seems it was already reported. Here is the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10401)

Secondary Edit:
I reported the issue on GitHub and it seems the issue is only appearing on Android API 33.

Comment: Code looks fine. *"I get no effect from changing the shadow radius at all."* Have you tried extreme changes? `Radius="2"`, `Radius="99"`? (I see that it also isn't feathering, but want to determine whether it is completely ignoring the setting.)  Does `Opacity` have any effect? Regardless, I recommend creating a new issue at `github maui issues`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have tried changing the `Radius` and `Opacity` settings to various degrees. It seems that the `Radius` on the Xiaomi 11T is always 1. I came to the conclusion because I can get the same effect on the Pixel 5 by setting the `Radius` to 1. The `Opacity` setting is being applied as I can see the shadow changing with each new setting on every device.

Comment: So it's a device-specific issue that only occurs on Xiaomi? Interesting ngl, Have you tried Debugging if the value actually changes on the control?

Comment: @FreakyAli I haven't thought of that. Might be that the radius setting is not getting set at all on Xiaomi devices (that is MIUI).

Comment: Exactly so have you tested this?

Comment: @FreakyAli I just tested this and it still doesn't work. Put up a binding for the radius property and also bound a slider and a label to it. The value is clearly changing but the effect stays the same. Values were from 0 - 100 float. Pixel 5 worked like a charm but the Xiaomi devices didn't